# Run local C# application on loading php web application

Tags: javascript, c#, php

I work on php web application that uses C# Background application to deal with com ports to read and write to smart cards, so every time i need to use the functions i must run the C# application then execute the read or write, so is there any way to run this app automatically if it closed everytime i Logged in to the website.

Thank You

Comment: What OS? On Windows, you can run it as a service and have the web server communicate with it via IPC (named pipes, sockets, etc). As it is, your question is too vague to answer.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp On windows Yes , and my question is if i can run it from local, or as a service but i don't know the way to do it

Comment: What server? IIS? [PHP - Can't open .exe files with exec command](//stackoverflow.com/q/12745098)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp you didn't get what i want to do, the .exe file will open from the client local hard disk it won't be on the server for now.